# Getting View from activity in android for screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want trying to implement a screenshot feature for android. For that i want a view from android's activity. I am not allowed to use the `R.id.viewid` as I am implementing this as part of library and not application. so I am trying to use `activity.getWindow().getDecorView` 
Please let me know if getting DecorView is right approach ? or there should be some another method.

MyActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();    
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test";
        Screenshot.takeScreenshot (this.getWindow().getDecorView(), mPath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Screenshot.getBitmapScreenshot(this.getWindow().getDecorView()));
    }
```

Screenshot.java

```
public static void takeScreenshot(View view, String filePath) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapScreenshot(view);
        File imageFile = new File(filePath);
        imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static Bitmap getBitmapScreenshot(View view) {

        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null)
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;


    }
```

I am getting following error.

```
    3795-3795/com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp, PID: 3795

        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp/com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                at com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp.Screenshot.getBitmapScreenshot(Screenshot.java:49)
                at com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp.Screenshot.takeScreenshot(Screenshot.java:24)
                at com.screenshot.nileshagrawal.screenshotapp.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:32)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
                at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6019)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2940)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: ok. so decor view is null.

Comment: i dont know about that, but yes app crashes at `Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` line where the getWidth is called on null, so might be decor view is null.

Comment: @downvote : can i know the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting this method in onPause() as the view get ready for any modification during onResume().So either put some delay in the onResume (take the screenshot in async manner using handlers) or if the screen shot is not that critical take the same in onPause() and call the function before super.onPause() call. In one of the stackoverflow post the code below sample is working.
 I have tested the same in onPause().

use this method

```
 public static String takeScreenshot(Activity activity) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap resultBitmap = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        String encodedImg = null;
        Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), "Taking screenshot",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            View v1 = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            resultBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                    v1.getMeasuredWidth(), v1.getMeasuredHeight(), false);
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(),
            //resultBitmap, "myScreenshot2", "Test2");

            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            resultBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            encodedImg = new String(Base64.encode(bitmapdata, Base64.DEFAULT));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Could not capture the screen image");
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        } finally {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            if (resultBitmap != null) {
                resultBitmap.recycle();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.reset();
            }
            return encodedImg;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing getWindow().getDecorView for this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

I think the rest will work

Comment: No, this will not help me, as i am creating this as a part of library. so i cannot ask for the view from the user.

Comment: @NileshAgrawal - FYI - it's not a view from the user. As you can see it's an ID from android.R.id namespace - it's the layout that wraps user's content - thus always present.